# Working out new workers paid compared to previous workers using worker ID

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been querying a database which has the data of workers who have been paid for a specific company which is reffered to as a site id. However, i wantto get the date each day from the specified dates, the total hours which have been worked on that day and the total number of workers which have been paid that day. That works fine with the following query. However, the date starts from 25/09/2017. The total number of workers paid is 122. But i want query which would show me how many new workers have been paid n the 26th which were not paid on the 25. and then the same for the 27th and so on. The code which has been done so far is following:

```
USE database

GO



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ts') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ts

SELECT
    ts.[IsAdjustment],
    ts.[DateFrom],
    ts.[Id] AS [TsId],
    tl.*
INTO #ts
FROM
            [Timesheet]     ts
INNER JOIN  [TimesheetLine] tl  ON  ts.[Id] = tl.[TimesheetId]
WHERE
    ts.[SiteId] = 901

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tsl') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tsl

CREATE TABLE #tsl (
    [WorkerId] INT,
    [DateFrom] DATE,
    [DateWorked] DATE,
    [WorkUnitId] INT,
    [EntryGroupId] INT,
    [Hours] DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 0, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day1_Standard_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day1_standard_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 1, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day2_Standard_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day2_standard_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 2, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day3_Standard_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day3_standard_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 3, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day4_Standard_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day4_standard_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 4, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day5_Standard_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day5_standard_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 5, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day6_Standard_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day6_standard_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 6, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day7_Standard_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day7_standard_hours], 0) <> 0

INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 0, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day1_Overtime_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day1_Overtime_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 1, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day2_Overtime_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day2_Overtime_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 2, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day3_Overtime_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day3_Overtime_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 3, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day4_Overtime_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day4_Overtime_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 4, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day5_Overtime_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day5_Overtime_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 5, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day6_Overtime_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day6_Overtime_hours], 0) <> 0
INSERT INTO #tsl SELECT [WorkerId], [DateFrom], DATEADD(day, 6, [DateFrom]), [WorkUnitId], [EntryGroupId], [Day7_Overtime_hours] FROM #ts WHERE ISNULL([Day7_Overtime_hours], 0) <> 0

DELETE FROM #tsl WHERE [DateWorked] < '2017-09-25' OR [DateWorked] > '2017-12-31'


-- ****************************************************************

SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d.[DateWorked], 103) AS [DateWorked],
    SUM(d.[Hours]) AS [Total_Hours],
    COUNT([Workerid]) AS [PRN_Paid]
FROM
(SELECT
    [WorkerId],
    [DateFrom],
    [DateWorked],
    SUM([Hours]) AS [Hours] 
FROM 
    #tsl
GROUP BY

    [WorkerId],
    [DateFrom],
    [DateWorked]) d INNER JOIN [Worker] w ON d.[WorkerId] = w.[Id]

GROUP BY [DateWorked]
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, DateWorked) ASC
```

Expected Outcome

```
DateWorked  Total_Hours PRN_Paid    New_PRN_Paid
25/09/2017   1376.94     122            0
26/09/2017   1403.40     126            12
27/09/2017   1477.25     136            16
28/09/2017   1432.10     133            3
29/09/2017   1305.49     123            1
```

So the worker id which is coming as new prn paid for the 29th doesn't exist in any of the prn paid worker ids before the 29th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i want query which would show me how many new workers have been paid n the 26th which were not paid on the 25

Ok, in its most basic form you want a `where not exists`:

```
select *
from #ts1 x1
where dateworked between '2017-09-25' and '2017-09-29'
and not exists (select 1 
                from #ts1 x2 
                where x1.WorkerId = x2.WorkerId 
                and x2.dateworked < x1.dateworked) -- This excludes workers who worked on an earlier day
```

From here you can start with aggregation, change the date queries around, etc

Comment: This would work for one date but i need it to work between 2 dates for instance from 25-09-2017 to 31-12-2017

Comment: @ShahbazHussain Then explain your question better. Edit your question and provide expected output

Comment: DateWorked Total_Hours PRN_Paid New_PRN_Paid
25/09/2017 1376.94 122 0
26/09/2017 1403.40 126 6
27/09/2017 1477.25 136 9
28/09/2017 1432.10 133 10
29/09/2017 1305.49 123 20

Comment: that's the expected outcome. For example, the new prn for 29th is 20 which means their worker id has not been paid for the previous dates

Comment: Theres the expected outcome

Comment: where would this go in the actual query?